# Focus kickout on custom redux form input

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I got this redux form input :

```
<Field
  component={MyCustomComponent}
  name={name}
  type={type}
/>
```

Using this custom element (bootstrap) :

```
<FormGroup controlId='login'>
  <FormControl name={name} placeholder={name} value={props.value} onChange={input.onChange} {...props} />
</FormGroup>
```

And I use it like so :

```
<Input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' {...email} />
<Input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' {...password} />
```

Something strange happens. When I select the input and I try to write something inside, I am automatically kicked out of the input (focus).
When I try to write it again, everything works.

It's only when I select it for the first time after that the page is loaded.

Full form :

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onLogin)}>
  <div>
    <Input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' {...email} />
    <Input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' {...password} />
  </div>
  <Button type='submit' bsStyle='primary' bsSize='large' active>
    <FormattedMessage
      id='login.select-label'
      defaultMessage='Login'
    />
  </Button>
</Form>
```

Full input :

```
export const Input = (props) => {
  const { name, type } = props

  const MyCustomComponent = ({input}: props) => (
    <FormGroup controlId='login'>
      <FormControl name={name} placeholder={name} value={props.value} onChange={input.onChange} {...props} />
    </FormGroup>
  )

  return (
    <Field
      component={MyCustomComponent}
      name={name}
      type={type}
    />

  )
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of the entire form, where it all comes together?

Comment: Yes, I'll update my post